# How to elegantly structure a chain of requests/callbacks using dojo?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, deferred

I've used dojo a fair bit but don't entirely have my head around `dojo.Deferred` (or at least I haven't used all the available features). I've been doing some reading about it and was wondering if the following scenario would be a suitable place to use a Deferred as a more elegant approach?  Or if not Deferred, is `Promise` or some other sort of chaining technique available in dojo that can achieve the following in a more readable/sequential manner?

```
var _this = this;

var secondCallback =  function( res ) {
    console.debug('All is complete Result [' + res +']');
};

var firstCallback = function( res ) {
    if(res == 'true') 
        my.lib.processRPC( my.rpc.module.DoSecondStep( _this.user_id ), secondCallback );
};

my.lib.processRPC( my.rpc.module.CheckFirstStep(), firstCallback );
```

If so, how would this look?  How would Deferred be used here?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, try it. BTW: A "Promise" is just something like a "frozen Deferred" where you can only add callbacks, but don't change state.

Answer (score 1):

I've dummied your RPC module with a simple window.setTimeout to simulate asynchronous callbacks after network delay, and replaced _this.user_id with _this_user_id, and possibly other tweaks.

Runnable example: http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/4c296/0

```
/* In resopnse to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217904/how-to-elegantly-structure-a-chain-of-requests-callbacks-using-dojo */
require([
  "dojo/_base/Deferred"
], function(Deferred) {

  var my_lib = function() {};
  my_lib.processRPC = function(value, def) {
    // simulate a long lived network call or whatever
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("rpc  has fired");
      def.resolve(value);
    }, 1000);
  }


  var my_rpc_module = function() {};
  my_rpc_module.CheckFirstStep = function() {
    console.log("CheckFirstStep here.");
    return 'true';
  }
  my_rpc_module.DoSecondStep = function(userid) {
    console.log("CheckSecondStep here for userid " +userid + ".");
    return 'finished';
  }

  var _this_user_id = "Mr Blobby";

  var secondCallback = new Deferred();

  secondCallback.then(function(res) {
    console.debug('All is complete Result [' + res +']');
  });

  var firstCallback = new Deferred();
  firstCallback.then(function( res ) {
    if(res == 'true') {
        my_lib.processRPC( my_rpc_module.DoSecondStep( _this_user_id ), secondCallback );
    }
  });


  my_lib.processRPC( my_rpc_module.CheckFirstStep(), firstCallback );

})
```

Comment: This just adds one layer of complexity by using Deferred callbacks, but neither uses them for chaining nor elegantly structures them as requested.

Answer (score 0):

`my.lib.processRPC` would need to return a [Promise](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/promises/) for the processing. ["Deferred"](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/deferreds/) is the interface to reject/fulfil a promise, you probably don't want to export those methods - you only return a Promise from the private-scoped Deferred, on which the callbacks can be installed.

I'm no Dojo expert, you might need to adapt the following codes to the exact syntax. A implementation close to your scenario - I expect `my.rpc.module.DoSecondStep( _this.user_id )` beeing only a function to create option objects - would look like this:

```
my.lib.processRPC = function(options)
    var d = new Deferred();
    // ...
    return d.getPromise();
    // do some heavy and/or asynchronous processing and call
    d.resolve(result) // somewhen in the future
};

// narrative code:
my.lib.processRPC( my.rpc.module.getFirstStep() ).then(function(result) {
    if (result)
        return my.lib.processRPC( my.rpc.module.getSecondStep( _this.user_id ) )
          .then( function( res ) {
            console.debug('All is complete Result [' + res +']');
          });
     else
        return /* false */ result;
}).addCallback(console.log.bind(console, "everything finished"));
```

But I suggest that the `doStepX` function really should do the processing themselves. So they should return Deferreds/Promises (eventually by calling `processRPC` internally), and reject them when they are not successful. The Deferred will "bubble" such errors.

```
my.rpc.module.doFirstStep = function() {
    var d = new Deferred();
    // ...
    return d.getPromise();
    // do some heavy and/or asynchronous processing and call
    d.resolve(result) // or
    d.reject(error) // somewhen in the future
};
my.rpc.module.doSecondStep = function(id) {
    // returning a Promise, as above
};

// really narrative code:
my.rpc.module.doFirstStep()
  .then(my.rpc.module.doSecondStep)
  .addCallbacks(function( res ) {
    console.log('All is complete Result [' + res +']');
  }, function (err) {
    console.log('Something happened: [' + err +']');
  });
```

Note that `doSecondStep` receives the (success) result of the first deferred as an argument. If you don't want that or need to specify additional parameters without calling, you'll need to use something like [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or a wrapper function:

```
...then(function firstCallback() {
    return my.rpc.module.DoSecondStep( _this.user_id );
})...
```